# I need to read an ajax post with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am attempting to update a database using ajax and PHP. Right now, i am just testing to see if my receiving PHP file is getting the POST data by echoing it, but all I get back is an 'undefined index' error.

Here's my sending code:

```
var content = $(".homeContent").html();
                var dataString = "homepage|content|"+content;
                //var 
                $.ajax(
                        {

                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Update.php",
                        data: "dataString="+dataString,
                        success: function (result) {
                                console.log(dataString);
                        }
                });
```

and here is my receiving file (Update.php):

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['dataString'];
?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: Try using `data: {dataString: dataString}`. You may not be encoding the parameter properly. Although that should just result in a partial value, not `undefined index`.

Comment: No, POST gives the same error

Comment: Change console.log(dataString); tp console.log(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Ajax (JavaScript):

```
$.post( "Update.php", { dataString: "some String" } );
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['dataString'];
?>
```

Comment: can we see the contents of `$_POST`,  do a `echo print_r($_POST, true);`

Comment: All it prints is Array ( )

Comment: it's empty. nothing was ever posted. Now I would suggest debugging the client side. Use chrome developer tools and check the network section, in POST inspect request data, see if anything was actually sent.

Comment: In the Network section of developer tools, when I look at the Response tab while Update.php is selected, I can see the array as it should be. My content is there.

Comment: So why does my Update.php page give me an error if it's getting the post data?

Comment: @BarryBeach I don't think it ever got the post data because the array was empty when you did `echo print_r($_POST, true);` You mentioned it just printed `Array()` - which actually indicates an empty array.

Comment: I would suggest checking your `php.ini` file for misconfiguration. for example I did this `cat /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini | grep 'post_max'` to check the maximum post data size is set correctly. Make sure it's not saying something like `post_max_size=8MB`.  It shouldn't have MB, just M. You may find this link helpful: http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/

Comment: I have never had a post size issue with my test server, and the data I'm passing with this script is about 0.5K. I checked anyway, and it does say post_max_size=8M.  I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I got it working. I think the issue was that Chrome was out of date. Thanks everyone for your responses.